# Setting Visibility based on another control's visualstate

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, visualstatemanager

Is it possible to set visibility on a `Grid` or other element based on the visual state of another control? I'm just starting to wrap my head around the `VisualStateManager` concept (having found that style triggers can't be used in universal apps) but can't work out if this can be done or not.

To my specific scenario, am I able to set the visibility of one or more elements if a specific item/index in a `ListView` is currently selected? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would maintain the `ListView` selection in a property of the viewmodel and bind `Grid.Visibility` to that property. You will need an `IValueConverter` to convert from the selected item's datatype to `System.Windows.Visibility`, which is required for `Grid.Visibility` binding.

In case the logic to determine visiblity is more complex, e.g. requires application state, you could add a property `bool IsImportantItemSelected` to the viewmodel and bind `Grid.Visibility` to this property. This approach allows you to keep the complex logic in the viewmodel. You'd need an `IValueConverter` again to convert from `bool` to `System.Windows.Visibility`.

Comment: Thanks Silverstein. This helped push me in the right direction to get the outcome desired.